# Google Big Query to look at data of 2 specific dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to Big Query. I am trying to do a where condition to only select yesterday's data and that of same day last year (in this case, 10/25/2021 data and 10/25/2020 data). I know how to select a range of data, but I couldn't figure out a way to only select those 2 days of data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like Big Query won't let me use the new metric I created in the "where" condition. I created a new column: PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) as my_date. I tried to do a where condition as: where my_date in  ('20201027' , '20211027') to test, but I got error on the 'in'. Date is a string, here is an example for date: 20190102. Wondering if there's anything I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using BigQuery functions to define dates. You can read about them [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_sub).

```
WHERE DATE(your_date_field) IN ((DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

This is dynamic to any day that you run the query. It will take the current date, then subtract 1 day. For the other date, it will take the current date and subtract 1 day and then 1 year, making it yesterday's date 1 year prior.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best approach I believe, I also didn't feel comfortable by just giving dates certain values. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting this as your answer. :)

Comment: Just did! A quick follow up question wondering if you can help: when I wrote where date in (), I got an error on "in", wondering if it's because date is a string and it won't work with "in"? Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If your date is in a string format, you need to **parse** the string to a date. BigQuery has function called PARSE_DATE(format_string, date_string) when it will parse a string to a date using the format you specify. Then it will recognize it as a date. You can read and see examples here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE date_my_field IN (DATE('2021-10-25'), DATE('2020-10-25'))
```

Use `IN` which is a short cut for `OR` operator

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (less verbose approach - especially if you remove time zone)

```
select 
  current_date('America/Los_Angeles') - 1 as yesterday,  
  date(current_date('America/Los_Angeles') - 1 - interval 1 year) same_day_last_year
```

with output

[image]

So, now you can use it in your WHERE clause as in below example (with dummy data via CTE)

```
with data as (
  select your_date_field
  from unnest(generate_date_array(current_date() - 1000, current_date())) your_date_field
)
select *
from data
where your_date_field in (
  current_date('America/Los_Angeles') - 1,  
  date(current_date('America/Los_Angeles') - 1 - interval 1 year) 
)
```

with output

[image]